# What is the need of converting integer encoding to binary encoding?

Tags: machine-learning, encoding, scikit-learn, data-processing, one-hot-encoding

What is the need of converting integer encoding to binary encoding? I have checked different websites, textbooks but couldn't get what exactly it does and what is the need. We have categorical data and we can convert it to integer so far so good. However, what is the need for binary encoding?

I have check the answer at 
[Why does one hot encoding improve machine learning performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469835/why-does-one-hot-encoding-improve-machine-learning-performance)
However, it's still not clear. It says we can get their own weights but wasn't that possible even if we had integer value?

Comment: So that the model wont assume an ordinal relationship between those values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does one hot encoding improve machine learning performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469835/why-does-one-hot-encoding-improve-machine-learning-performance)

Comment: @petezurich Mine is a bit different. Please check the question, I have updated it.

Comment: @VivekKumar can you please elaborate.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to elaborate @VivekKumar's comment in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you encode i.e. categorical variables `A`, `B`, `C` to integers `1`, `2`, `3` many classifiers will «assume» that A (=1) is **less** than B (=2) or C (=3). This simply is a wrong assumption about the relationship of your categoricals.

Therefore you have to one hot encode.

Comment: At last, an answer that really meant something. Thank you so much.

Comment: @GurjasSingh You're welcome! :0) And in the same context you may have a look into the so called *dummy variable trap* eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51914169/dummy-variable-in-multiple-linear-regression